# Getting Values from comparing Two Arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two array one is the state like this

```
const [state,setState] = useState([])
```

and the another one is am getting from a form when it is submitted;

```
   ids = [4,5,6]
setState(ids)
```

Now, when i update the state second time the values are there i.e 4,5,6 in the state.
so the values are getting duplicated ie 4,5,6,4,5,6

What i want is to make sure that only the elements which is not present in the array gets pushed not all,and i get the valid output like following.

```
4,5,6,7
```

If 7 is added.

What i did is like this, which is totally wrong

```
 const filterss = [...state];
      setState([]);
      filterss.push(values);
      setState(filterss);
```

Comment: Seems like you want to use a `Set` instead of an array

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const ids=[4,5,6]
let formSubmitIds=[4,5,6,7]
let uniquieIds=[...new Set([...ids,...formSubmitIds])]
console.log(uniquieIds)
```

Simply use this logic to setState accordingly i.e `setState(uniquieIds)`

**ids** are the stored values in state

**formSubmitIds** is the new array which you are getting on submit of form

`[...ids,...formSubmitIds]` will merge both arrays

**Set** is used to remove duplicates

`[......new Set]` will convert Set back to an array with unique ids only

Answer (score 0):

```
  const filters = [...state];
  values.forEach(item => {
    if (filters.indexOf(item) < 0) {
      filters.push(item);
    }
  })
  setState(filters);
```

Answer (score 0):

First push all the old and new values in a single array then try using Set() to get unique values in the array.
Here's the code.

```
setState(new Set(arrayName))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set()` **constructor** to achieve your goal.

Try:

```
const [state, setState] = useState([])

const ids = [4,5,6]
const formSubmittedIds = [4,5,6,7]

setState([...new Set([...ids, ...formSubmittedIds])]) // Sets [4, 5, 6, 7] to the state
```

Happy coding :)